# How to handle user's upload image or video from a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my iOS app I have a `WKWebView` that loads my website.

In my website there is a HTML form that allows users to upload images.

I want to receive when user click on this form attach button so I can request permission for Camera and Photo Library. If user rejects the access I want to dismiss the click.

If user did not select an image from photo library and clicked cancel. The WKWebView reloads my page. I do not want it to reload my page.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self
```

Which `delegate` functions are suitable to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into injecting a JS callback for the button's onclick event into the WKWebView with WKUserScript.

You can find a similar question and a great answer on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687162/how-to-inject-javascript-callback-to-detect-onclick-event-using-ios-wkwebview).

Comment: I want to avoid JS.